# Feature selection in cross validation

Tags: cross-validation, feature-selection

In cross validation should feature selection be applied only on the training data or also on the test set?

Comment: [This thread](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/64147/28500) goes into extensive detail. Note that your setting aside of a separate training set might give poor performance unless you have thousands of samples; see the answer from Frank Harrell in that thread.